# WordPress htaccess permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I migrated from a Windows server to a Linux one and I am very new to htaccess. Also, I changed my permalinks structure from /year/month/post to /post . To make sure the old search engine links still worked I added the following line to the htaccess file which is working fine to redirect the old URLs to the new ones, but read on:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www. keptlight .com/$3
```

Now, my year/month archives always point to the site root since /year/month/ are being stripped. For instance:

```
www. keptlight .com/2014/02/ orchis-is-coming-2/
```

is properly redirected to:

```
www. keptlight .com/orchis-is-coming-2/
```

But the monthly posts for a given month:

`www. keptlight .com/2011/06/` or any other year/month is always redirected to:

```
www.keptlight.com
```

Is there a way to overcome this problem and properly display the monthly archives when only year/month/ follows the domain with no post title?

Thank you in advance.

Cemal Ekin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})(/.+)+$ http://www.keptlight.com$3
```

Comment: Thank you Aleksandar. It worked exactly the way I wanted, thank you.

Comment: I am sure that you can not get better help anywhere then here at stackoverflow :) cheers!